# can we put (null,null) in map type Collection in Hibernate...?

Tags: hibernate

Can we put (null,"null") in a map type collection to store in a DB? Also, how can it be retrived?

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps do allow for 1 null key, and as many null values as you want.